Capture HTTP response header and payload in Lambda extension
I am working on an AWS Lambda extension which is deployed as an external extension with a Lambda function that handles HTTP requests. I want to capture HTTP request and response header and payload in that extension. I am able to capture the HTTP request header and body using the Lambda runtime API, but I could not find a mechanism to capture the response data. I tried the telemetry events (platform.rundoneDone), but it does not include the HTTP response data sent by the Lambda function. I need to get HTTP response code at least and correlate that with the request.
One possible option that I have got is to capture the logs using telemetry API and then parse the logs to find response data. But that depends on the application with it generates some sort of access logs. In addition to that, these logs will not have the request id to correlate the response with request.
It would be really helpful if someone can suggest a mechanism to capture the HTTP response information in the external Lambda extension.

You can achieve that by creating a lambda runtime api proxy. This blog post gives the detail on how that works.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/enhancing-runtime-security-and-governance-with-the-aws-lambda-runtime-api-proxy-extension/
